# How do I force the download of a .zip file, with contents retrieved using drupal_http_request()?

Tags: 7, hooks

when i do this curl request my files are getting saved in drupal root instead of getting downloaded to browser in the bottom. can anyone help me what wrong am i doing here. below is the code i'm using.

```
$product_name = "myproduct"; 
$zipFile = $product_name.".zip"; //Local Zip File Path     

$options_array = array (
  'method' => 'GET',
  'headers' => array(
    'Authorization' => 'Basic somepassword',  
    'Content-Type' => 'application/text',
    'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment',  
    'charset' => 'utf-8', 
    'Cache-Control' => 'no-cache' ,    
  ),
);
$url = "someurl";

$result = drupal_http_request($url,$options_array);
$fp = fopen($zipFile, "w");
header('Cache-Control: no-cache'); 
header('Content-Length: '.strlen($result->data));
header('Content-Type: application/text');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$fp);
fwrite($fp, $result->data);
fclose($fp);
echo $zipFile;
```

Comment: So `curl` is doing exactly what it's supposed to do. But what exactly are you trying to achieve? Please update your question for clarification.

Comment: I believe I've updated the title to be what you are trying to achieve. If this is correct, then please update the contents to match the title. Or else, please update both the title and content to give more information about what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: i want my file to download on browser instead of drupal root

Comment: So does the title match your problem? The contents of your post are talking about Curl, but you are not using Curl.

Comment: i used curl and drupal_http_request , using both gives me same result. but then i found out that using drupal_http_request is good.

Comment: also in the below solution the filename is not correctly rendered instead it takes the name of the last argument from the url. How can i make the filename to be the one from GET request

Answer (score 1):

In the same way you are using drupal_http_request() to make your remote request, there is a Drupal API for forcing a file download.

To do this, you will first need to create the file in the temporary directory so it can be served. You can do this using [file_unmanaged_save_data()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_unmanaged_save_data/7.x), setting the destination to start with (or be) `temporary://`, and passing the data in drupal_http_request() to be the contents of the zip file.

Then, you will force the download of the file with [file_transfer()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_transfer/7.x). This will force the browser to download the file. You can use the the file you crated above, referring to it with the `temporary://` stream wrapper.

```
// Step 1: Make HTTP Request using drupal_http_request()
// Step 2: Validate successful request
// Step 3: Create .zip file in temporary files directory, using file_unmanaged_save_data(), passing result of request made in Step 1 to be contents of .zip file
// Step 4: Serve file using file_transfer(), passing it the URI of the temporary:// file created in step 3
```

Note that the contents retrieved from the remote URL must be those of a valid .zip file.

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me, thanks @Jaypan for the suggestion.

```
  $result = drupal_http_request($url,$options_array);
  $destination = 'public://swagger_files/' . $zipFile;
  // what to do when the destination file already exists
  $replace = FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE;
  $my_file_obj = file_save_data($result->data, $destination, $replace);
  $headers = file_get_content_headers($my_file_obj);
  file_transfer($my_file_obj->uri,$headers);
```